# Selenium webdriver not identifying the web element in the HTML page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the testing of a web application whose HTML is rendered via javascript and not Java. I am able to login into the application using selenium as the login is just a HTML page. But once I enter the application, selenium webdriver isn't able to identify the web elements. 
I am using Selenium 2 + Java.
I have even tried saving the web application as a HTML page and try accessing the web elements. No luck there as well.

Framework used is cucumber.

```
package Junit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import testBase.TestBase1;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class Feature3StepDef extends TestBase1{
    @Given("^the application is open$")
    public void the_application_is_open() throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
          ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
        driver.get("http://******************/ccb-uata/SPLApp/cis.jsp");
        System.out.println("I am In given");
    }

    @When("^User enters \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void User_enters_and(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);      
        WebElement user=driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
        System.out.println("element is:" +user);
        user.sendKeys(arg1);
        WebElement psswd = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        psswd.sendKeys(arg2);
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.name("login"));
        button.click();
        System.out.println("I am In when");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*body/div/table[@id='headerTable']"));
        System.out.println("div element: " +elem);
        Thread.sleep(100000);
        System.out.println(arg1);

    }

    @Then("^the application should login$")
    public void the_application_should_login() throws Throwable {
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("I am In then");
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<!--
    ******************************************************************
    * Program name:      multiSearchNameData
    * Program location:  /ci/controlCentral
    * Program version:   1
    * Program template:  UIXSD
    * Template file:     //Release_Services/release/FW/V2.1.0/splapp/applications/root/WEB-INF/uiXSL/newSearchData.xsl 
    * Template revision: 3
    * Included XSL versions: 
    *   common           
    *   commonGrid       6
    *   commonGrid-xsl   5
    * 
    * Labels:
    *     Table$Field  -  label   (element type, js_name) 
    *     $PER_ACCT_INFO  -  Person/Account   (element type='IL' , jsName='ENTITY_INFO') 
    *     $PREMISE_LBL  -  Premise   (element type='IL' , jsName='PREM_INFO') 
    *     $ID_TYPE_LBL  -  ID Type   (element type='IL' , jsName='ID_TYPE') 
    *     $ID_NBR_LBL  -  ID Nbr   (element type='IL' , jsName='PER_ID_NBR') 
    *     $ACCT_ID  -  Account ID   (element type='HD' , jsName='ACCT_ID') 
    *     $PER_ID  -  Person ID   (element type='HD' , jsName='PER_ID') 
    *     $PREM_ID  -  Premise ID   (element type='HD' , jsName='PREM_ID') 
    * Widget Info:  
    *     Widget_ID , Element Type - label info - label 
    *     SEARCH_RESULTS:x$ENTITY_INFO, IL - $PER_ACCT_INFO -  Person/Account
    *     SEARCH_RESULTS:x$ACCT_INFO, IL
    *     SEARCH_RESULTS:x$PREM_INFO, IL - $PREMISE_LBL -  Premise
    *     SEARCH_RESULTS:x$ID_TYPE, IL - $ID_TYPE_LBL -  ID Type
    *     SEARCH_RESULTS:x$PER_ID_NBR, IL - $ID_NBR_LBL -  ID Nbr
    *     SEARCH_RESULTS:x$ACCT_ID, HD - $ACCT_ID -  Account ID
    *     SEARCH_RESULTS:x$PER_ID, HD - $PER_ID -  Person ID
    *     SEARCH_RESULTS:x$PREM_ID, HD - $PREM_ID -  Premise ID
    *
    ******************************************************************
  -->
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cisDisabled.css?ltr">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../cisEnabled.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../code/xslListGridSupport.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../code/xslSearchDataSupport.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../code/common.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    var isSearchData = true;
    var main = parent.main;
    var searchListModel = parent.searchListModel;

    var searchClient
    // Can go in support, onLoad?
    if (parent.isEmbedded) {
       searchClient = parent.parent
    } else {
       searchClient = parent.opener
    }

    var theListName = 'SEARCH_RESULTS';
    var emptyLine = false;


    var isCSSCompliant = false

    var majorBrowserVersion = navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE (\d+)/)[1]
    if (majorBrowserVersion < 6){
        isCSSCompliant = false
    }


    var myNavigationKeys = [ 
            'multiSearchNameData'
    ]


    var allFieldPairs = [
        ["xX", "xX", "xX"]

        ]





    function contextKeys() {
      return [
        {jsName: "", altName: "", contextInstance: ""}

      ];
    };



    // cache element types and data class info

var elementMetaData

function initializeElementMetaData() {
    self.elementMetaData = {

            'ENTITY_INFO': {
          jsName: 'ENTITY_INFO',
          elementType: 'IL',
          uiRow: '1',
          uiColumn: '1',
          fieldName: 'PER_ACCT_INFO',
          fieldDataType: 'CHAR',
          fieldExtendedDataType: '',
          fieldPrecision: '60'
        },
            'ACCT_INFO': {
          jsName: 'ACCT_INFO',
          elementType: 'IL',
          uiRow: '1',
          uiColumn: '1',
          fieldName: '',
          fieldDataType: '',
          fieldExtendedDataType: '',
          fieldPrecision: ''
        },
            'PREM_INFO': {
          jsName: 'PREM_INFO',
          elementType: 'IL',
          uiRow: '1',
          uiColumn: '2',
          fieldName: 'PREMISE_LBL',
          fieldDataType: 'CHAR',
          fieldExtendedDataType: '',
          fieldPrecision: '1'
        },
            'ID_TYPE': {
          jsName: 'ID_TYPE',
          elementType: 'IL',
          uiRow: '1',
          uiColumn: '3',
          fieldName: 'ID_TYPE_LBL',
          fieldDataType: 'CHAR',
          fieldExtendedDataType: '',
          fieldPrecision: '1'
        },
            'PER_ID_NBR': {
          jsName: 'PER_ID_NBR',
          elementType: 'IL',
          uiRow: '1',
          uiColumn: '4',
          fieldName: 'ID_NBR_LBL',
          fieldDataType: 'CHAR',
          fieldExtendedDataType: '',
          fieldPrecision: '1'
        },
            'ACCT_ID': {
          jsName: 'ACCT_ID',
          elementType: 'HD',
          uiRow: '1',
          uiColumn: '5',
          fieldName: 'ACCT_ID',
          fieldDataType: 'CHAR',
          fieldExtendedDataType: '',
          fieldPrecision: '10'
        },
            'PER_ID': {
          jsName: 'PER_ID',
          elementType: 'HD',
          uiRow: '1',
          uiColumn: '6',
          fieldName: 'PER_ID',
          fieldDataType: 'CHAR',
          fieldExtendedDataType: '',
          fieldPrecision: '10'
        },
            'PREM_ID': {
          jsName: 'PREM_ID',
          elementType: 'HD',
          uiRow: '1',
          uiColumn: '7',
          fieldName: 'PREM_ID',
          fieldDataType: 'CHAR',
          fieldExtendedDataType: '',
          fieldPrecision: '10'
        }
    }
}

var fkElements
function initializeFKElements(){
    self.fkElements = {

    }
}



// Start Product User exits

// End  Product User exits

</script><!-- Included file '/cm/ext_multiSearchNameData.jsp' not found --></head>
<body onload="loadFunctions();" onkeydown="main.onBodyKeyDown(event, document)" onclick="main.onBodyClick(event, document)">
<div xmlns:clientXSL="temp4" id="headerDivision">
<table id="headerTable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<colgroup id="headerColumn1">
<col>
</colgroup>
<colgroup id="headerColumn2">
<col>
</colgroup>
<colgroup id="headerColumn3">
<col>
</colgroup>
<colgroup id="headerColumn4">
<col>
</colgroup>
<colgroup style="display: none;" id="headerColumn5">
<col>
</colgroup>
<colgroup style="display: none;" id="headerColumn6">
<col>
</colgroup>
<colgroup style="display: none;" id="headerColumn7">
<col>
</colgroup>
<thead id="headerTableHead">
<tr class="gridLabel">
<td onclick="clickedSortBy('SEARCH_RESULTS','ENTITY_INFO')" style="cursor:hand" nowrap valign="middle" class="gridTd"><span>&nbsp;<span id="L_ENTITY_INFO" name="L_ENTITY_INFO">Person/Account</span><img class="sortImage" src="../images/sortUp.gif" id="SS_ENTITY_INFO" name="SS_ENTITY_INFO"></span></td><td onclick="clickedSortBy('SEARCH_RESULTS','PREM_INFO')" style="cursor:hand" nowrap valign="middle" class="gridTd"><span>&nbsp;<span id="L_PREM_INFO" name="L_PREM_INFO">Premise</span><img class="sortImage" src="../images/sortUp.gif" id="SS_PREM_INFO" name="SS_PREM_INFO"></span></td><td onclick="clickedSortBy('SEARCH_RESULTS','ID_TYPE')" style="cursor:hand" nowrap valign="middle" class="gridTd"><span>&nbsp;<span id="L_ID_TYPE" name="L_ID_TYPE">ID Type</span><img class="sortImage" src="../images/sortUp.gif" id="SS_ID_TYPE" name="SS_ID_TYPE"></span></td><td onclick="clickedSortBy('SEARCH_RESULTS','PER_ID_NBR')" style="cursor:hand" nowrap valign="middle" class="gridTd"><span>&nbsp;<span id="L_PER_ID_NBR" name="L_PER_ID_NBR">ID Nbr</span><img class="sortImage" src="../images/sortUp.gif" id="SS_PER_ID_NBR" name="SS_PER_ID_NBR"></span></td><td onclick="clickedSortBy('SEARCH_RESULTS','ACCT_ID')" style="cursor:hand" nowrap valign="middle" class="gridTd"><span>&nbsp;<span id="L_ACCT_ID" name="L_ACCT_ID">Account ID</span><img class="sortImage" src="../images/sortUp.gif" id="SS_ACCT_ID" name="SS_ACCT_ID"></span></td><td onclick="clickedSortBy('SEARCH_RESULTS','PER_ID')" style="cursor:hand" nowrap valign="middle" class="gridTd"><span>&nbsp;<span id="L_PER_ID" name="L_PER_ID">Person ID</span><img class="sortImage" src="../images/sortUp.gif" id="SS_PER_ID" name="SS_PER_ID"></span></td><td onclick="clickedSortBy('SEARCH_RESULTS','PREM_ID')" style="cursor:hand" nowrap valign="middle" class="gridTd"><span>&nbsp;<span id="L_PREM_ID" name="L_PREM_ID">Premise ID</span><img class="sortImage" src="../images/sortUp.gif" id="SS_PREM_ID" name="SS_PREM_ID"></span></td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _clientXSL;
    function templateRow(){
      if (_clientXSL) return _clientXSL;


      _clientXSL = '\x3CclientXSL\x3Atemplate\x20match\x3D\x22\x2F\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Avariable\x20name\x3D\x22startUIIndex\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Achoose\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Awhen\x20test\x3D\x22\x2Flist\x2FstartUIIndex\x2F\x40value\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x20select\x3D\x22\x2Flist\x2FstartUIIndex\x2F\x40value\x22\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Awhen\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aotherwise\x3E0\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aotherwise\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Achoose\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Avariable\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Avariable\x20name\x3D\x22oddEvenOffset\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Achoose\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Awhen\x20test\x3D\x22\x2Flist\x2FstartOnOddRow\x2F\x40value\x3D\x27true\x27\x22\x3E1\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Awhen\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aotherwise\x3E0\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aotherwise\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Achoose\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Avariable\x3E\x3Ctable\x20onkeypress\x3D\x22handleTRKeyPress\x28\x29\x22\x20onkeydown\x3D\x22handleTRKeyDown\x28\x29\x22\x20id\x3D\x22dataTable\x22\x20cellpadding\x3D\x222\x22\x20cellspacing\x3D\x220\x22\x3E\x3Ccolgroup\x20id\x3D\x22dataColumn1\x22\x3E\x3Ccol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcolgroup\x3E\x3Ccolgroup\x20id\x3D\x22dataColumn2\x22\x3E\x3Ccol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcolgroup\x3E\x3Ccolgroup\x20id\x3D\x22dataColumn3\x22\x3E\x3Ccol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcolgroup\x3E\x3Ccolgroup\x20id\x3D\x22dataColumn4\x22\x3E\x3Ccol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcolgroup\x3E\x3Ccolgroup\x20style\x3D\x22display\x3A\x20none\x3B\x22\x20id\x3D\x22dataColumn5\x22\x3E\x3Ccol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcolgroup\x3E\x3Ccolgroup\x20style\x3D\x22display\x3A\x20none\x3B\x22\x20id\x3D\x22dataColumn6\x22\x3E\x3Ccol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcolgroup\x3E\x3Ccolgroup\x20style\x3D\x22display\x3A\x20none\x3B\x22\x20id\x3D\x22dataColumn7\x22\x3E\x3Ccol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcol\x3E\x3C\x2Fcolgroup\x3E\x3Cthead\x20id\x3D\x22dataTableHead\x22\x3E\x3Ctr\x20style\x3D\x22visibility\x3A\x20hidden\x3B\x20height\x3A\x200\x25\x3B\x20position\x3A\x20absolute\x3B\x22\x20height\x3D\x220\x22\x20class\x3D\x22gridLabel\x22\x3E\x3Ctd\x20onclick\x3D\x22clickedSortBy\x28\x27SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x27\x2C\x27ENTITY\x5FINFO\x27\x29\x22\x20style\x3D\x22cursor\x3Ahand\x22\x20nowrap\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20class\x3D\x22gridTd\x22\x3E\x3Cspan\x3E \x3Cspan\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FENTITY\x5FINFO\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FENTITY\x5FINFO\x22\x3EPerson\x26\x23x2F\x3BAccount\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3Cimg\x20class\x3D\x22sortImage\x22\x20src\x3D\x22\x2E\x2E\x2Fimages\x2FsortUp\x2Egif\x22\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FENTITY\x5FINFO\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FENTITY\x5FINFO\x22\x3E\x3C\x2Fimg\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20onclick\x3D\x22clickedSortBy\x28\x27SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x27\x2C\x27PREM\x5FINFO\x27\x29\x22\x20style\x3D\x22cursor\x3Ahand\x22\x20nowrap\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20class\x3D\x22gridTd\x22\x3E\x3Cspan\x3E \x3Cspan\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FPREM\x5FINFO\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FPREM\x5FINFO\x22\x3EPremise\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3Cimg\x20class\x3D\x22sortImage\x22\x20src\x3D\x22\x2E\x2E\x2Fimages\x2FsortUp\x2Egif\x22\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FPREM\x5FINFO\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FPREM\x5FINFO\x22\x3E\x3C\x2Fimg\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20onclick\x3D\x22clickedSortBy\x28\x27SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x27\x2C\x27ID\x5FTYPE\x27\x29\x22\x20style\x3D\x22cursor\x3Ahand\x22\x20nowrap\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20class\x3D\x22gridTd\x22\x3E\x3Cspan\x3E \x3Cspan\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FID\x5FTYPE\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FID\x5FTYPE\x22\x3EID\x20Type\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3Cimg\x20class\x3D\x22sortImage\x22\x20src\x3D\x22\x2E\x2E\x2Fimages\x2FsortUp\x2Egif\x22\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FID\x5FTYPE\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FID\x5FTYPE\x22\x3E\x3C\x2Fimg\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20onclick\x3D\x22clickedSortBy\x28\x27SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x27\x2C\x27PER\x5FID\x5FNBR\x27\x29\x22\x20style\x3D\x22cursor\x3Ahand\x22\x20nowrap\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20class\x3D\x22gridTd\x22\x3E\x3Cspan\x3E \x3Cspan\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FPER\x5FID\x5FNBR\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FPER\x5FID\x5FNBR\x22\x3EID\x20Nbr\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3Cimg\x20class\x3D\x22sortImage\x22\x20src\x3D\x22\x2E\x2E\x2Fimages\x2FsortUp\x2Egif\x22\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FPER\x5FID\x5FNBR\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FPER\x5FID\x5FNBR\x22\x3E\x3C\x2Fimg\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20onclick\x3D\x22clickedSortBy\x28\x27SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x27\x2C\x27ACCT\x5FID\x27\x29\x22\x20style\x3D\x22cursor\x3Ahand\x22\x20nowrap\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20class\x3D\x22gridTd\x22\x3E\x3Cspan\x3E \x3Cspan\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FACCT\x5FID\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FACCT\x5FID\x22\x3EAccount\x20ID\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3Cimg\x20class\x3D\x22sortImage\x22\x20src\x3D\x22\x2E\x2E\x2Fimages\x2FsortUp\x2Egif\x22\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FACCT\x5FID\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FACCT\x5FID\x22\x3E\x3C\x2Fimg\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20onclick\x3D\x22clickedSortBy\x28\x27SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x27\x2C\x27PER\x5FID\x27\x29\x22\x20style\x3D\x22cursor\x3Ahand\x22\x20nowrap\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20class\x3D\x22gridTd\x22\x3E\x3Cspan\x3E \x3Cspan\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FPER\x5FID\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FPER\x5FID\x22\x3EPerson\x20ID\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3Cimg\x20class\x3D\x22sortImage\x22\x20src\x3D\x22\x2E\x2E\x2Fimages\x2FsortUp\x2Egif\x22\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FPER\x5FID\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FPER\x5FID\x22\x3E\x3C\x2Fimg\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20onclick\x3D\x22clickedSortBy\x28\x27SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x27\x2C\x27PREM\x5FID\x27\x29\x22\x20style\x3D\x22cursor\x3Ahand\x22\x20nowrap\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20class\x3D\x22gridTd\x22\x3E\x3Cspan\x3E \x3Cspan\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FPREM\x5FID\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FL\x5FPREM\x5FID\x22\x3EPremise\x20ID\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3Cimg\x20class\x3D\x22sortImage\x22\x20src\x3D\x22\x2E\x2E\x2Fimages\x2FsortUp\x2Egif\x22\x20id\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FPREM\x5FID\x22\x20name\x3D\x22D\x5FSS\x5FPREM\x5FID\x22\x3E\x3C\x2Fimg\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3C\x2Ftr\x3E\x3C\x2Fthead\x3E\x3Ctbody\x20id\x3D\x22dataTableBody\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Afor\x2Deach\x20select\x3D\x22\x2Flist\x2Felement\x22\x3E\x3Ctr\x20onclick\x3D\x22handleTRClick\x28\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x29\x22\x20uiRowIndex\x3D\x22\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Achoose\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Awhen\x20test\x3D\x22\x28position\x28\x29\x20\x2B\x20\x24oddEvenOffset\x29\x20mod\x202\x20\x3D\x200\x22\x3EgridAlt\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Awhen\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aotherwise\x3Egrid\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aotherwise\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Achoose\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3Ctd\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x7C\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3E\x20gridTd\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x3Enowrap\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x26\x23xa0\x3B\x3Cspan\x20name\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24ENTITY\x5FINFO\x22\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24ENTITY\x5FINFO\x22\x20style\x3D\x22margin\x2Dright\x3A\x200\x2E20\x20em\x3B\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3Edata\x20dc\x2DCHAR\x2DNONE\x2D60\x2D0\x20\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x20select\x3D\x22\x40ENTITY\x5FINFO\x22\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3Cdiv\x20style\x3D\x22margin\x2Dleft\x3A\x203\x20ex\x3B\x22\x3E\x3Cspan\x20name\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24ACCT\x5FINFO\x22\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24ACCT\x5FINFO\x22\x20style\x3D\x22margin\x2Dright\x3A\x200\x2E20\x20em\x3B\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3Edata\x20\x20\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x20select\x3D\x22\x40ACCT\x5FINFO\x22\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Fdiv\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20width\x3D\x22350\x22\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x7C\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20align\x3D\x22\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3E\x20gridTd\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x3Enowrap\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x26\x23xa0\x3B\x3Cspan\x20name\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24PREM\x5FINFO\x22\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24PREM\x5FINFO\x22\x20style\x3D\x22margin\x2Dright\x3A\x200\x2E20\x20em\x3B\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3Edata\x20dc\x2DCHAR\x2DNONE\x2D1\x2D0\x20\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x20select\x3D\x22\x40PREM\x5FINFO\x22\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x7C\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20align\x3D\x22\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3E\x20gridTd\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x3Enowrap\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x26\x23xa0\x3B\x3Cspan\x20name\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24ID\x5FTYPE\x22\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24ID\x5FTYPE\x22\x20style\x3D\x22margin\x2Dright\x3A\x200\x2E20\x20em\x3B\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3Edata\x20dc\x2DCHAR\x2DNONE\x2D1\x2D0\x20\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x20select\x3D\x22\x40ID\x5FTYPE\x22\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x7C\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20align\x3D\x22\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3E\x20gridTd\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x3Enowrap\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x26\x23xa0\x3B\x3Cspan\x20name\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24PER\x5FID\x5FNBR\x22\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24PER\x5FID\x5FNBR\x22\x20style\x3D\x22margin\x2Dright\x3A\x200\x2E20\x20em\x3B\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3Edata\x20dc\x2DCHAR\x2DNONE\x2D1\x2D0\x20\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x20select\x3D\x22\x40PER\x5FID\x5FNBR\x22\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Avalue\x2Dof\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x7C\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20align\x3D\x22\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3E\x20gridTd\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x3Enowrap\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x26\x23xa0\x3B\x3Cspan\x20name\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24ACCT\x5FID\x22\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24ACCT\x5FID\x22\x20style\x3D\x22margin\x2Dright\x3A\x200\x2E20\x20em\x3B\x20display\x3A\x20none\x3B\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3Edata\x20dc\x2DCHAR\x2DNONE\x2D10\x2D0\x20\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x7C\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20align\x3D\x22\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3E\x20gridTd\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x3Enowrap\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x26\x23xa0\x3B\x3Cspan\x20name\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24PER\x5FID\x22\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24PER\x5FID\x22\x20style\x3D\x22margin\x2Dright\x3A\x200\x2E20\x20em\x3B\x20display\x3A\x20none\x3B\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3Edata\x20dc\x2DCHAR\x2DNONE\x2D10\x2D0\x20\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3Ctd\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x7C\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x22\x20valign\x3D\x22middle\x22\x20align\x3D\x22\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3E\x20gridTd\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22nowrap\x22\x3Enowrap\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x26\x23xa0\x3B\x3Cspan\x20name\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24PREM\x5FID\x22\x20id\x3D\x22SEARCH\x5FRESULTS\x3A\x7Bposition\x28\x29\x20\x2D\x201\x20\x2B\x20\x24startUIIndex\x7D\x24PREM\x5FID\x22\x20style\x3D\x22margin\x2Dright\x3A\x200\x2E20\x20em\x3B\x20display\x3A\x20none\x3B\x22\x3E\x3CclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x20name\x3D\x22class\x22\x3Edata\x20dc\x2DCHAR\x2DNONE\x2D10\x2D0\x20\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Aattribute\x3E\x3C\x2Fspan\x3E\x3C\x2Ftd\x3E\x3C\x2Ftr\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Afor\x2Deach\x3E\x3C\x2Ftbody\x3E\x3C\x2Ftable\x3E\x3C\x2FclientXSL\x3Atemplate\x3E'

    // wrap template row with stylesheet
    _clientXSL = ' <clientXSL:stylesheet  xmlns:clientXSL="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">\n'
                   + '<clientXSL:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>\n'
                   + _clientXSL + '\n</clientXSL:stylesheet>'


      return _clientXSL;
    }

    var listName = 'SEARCH_RESULTS';
   </script><span style="position:absolute;"><img src="../images/expandScroll.gif" id="scrollControl" name="scrollControl" style="position:absolute; top:-17px; right:-1px; visibility:hidden;"><div id="dataDivision" onscroll="onTableScroll();"></div>
</span>
<iframe scrolling="auto" id="context" src="../blankEmpty.html" class="contextMenu" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 100 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: *[@id='headerDivision']
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_27'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
    at Junit.Feature3StepDef.User_enters_and(Feature3StepDef.java:53)
    at ?.When User enters "syahm" and "Powerful4"(Resources\Features\Feature3.feature:5)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == *[@id='headerDivision'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 343 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_27'
Session ID: bb4475ec-3408-43f3-a7d2-22e2c0b94b66
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=internet explorer, nativeEvents=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=7}]

Comment: The vast majority of the page's HTML elements are generated via JavaScript after the page loads.  You will need to wait until the elements have been created before attempting to access them.  I'm not sure what the Selenium methods to do so are but that is likely what you will need.

Answer (score 0):

**Wait Time**

Selenium only interacts with the DOM so we don't care about the code behind.  As far as the html rendered, it's probably a timing issue.  Run the test in debug mode and put a break point at the beginning of the test.  Then manually step through each step one at a time once the page has had time to load.

If it's a timing issue, you can doe one of two things:

1. Wait for page load by checking the document ready status.  [Here](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2013/09/webdriver-wait-for-document-ready-and.html) is a C# way of doing that.
2. Your second option is to wait for the element you're looking for to be present.  You can see a good example of this in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827395/selenium-java-cant-get-text-from-nested-element-without-printing-it).

Here is the suggestion from that post:

```
WebElement foundElement = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("myId")));
```

**Selector**

If it's not the wait time, it could be the selector isn't correct and you're not grabbing the right element.  XPath is the easiest way to fix that.

1. Open page in Chrome
2. Right click on element and choose inspect element
3. Chrome should show the html and you should be on that element.  Right click and Copy XPath
4. Change your selector to *driver.FindElement(By.XPath("selector you just found"));* Note you may need to tweak it slightly so you're not escaping quotes.
5. Run again with new selector in Chrome.  If it doesn't work, pause right before you select it and search again for the XPath and compare what you had before with what you have now.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I did try the suggestion provided. But still the element is not identified. Have tried even for a longer duration waiting period. Though the web page loads completely, the element is not identified.

Comment: Could it be your selector then?  I'm going to edit my post to include steps to verify the selector.

Comment: Hi Brantley, I did check this before commenting here. I am trying to just access the first tag. Have used all sorts of selectors to identify it. Unfortunately the application is compatible only with IE 7 and below. I have even tried getting the firebug for IE. But failed. Don't have admin rights on this system.

Comment: Do you have access to a webdev?  Putting an ID on the element often only takes a couple of seconds.  That would make it easy to select.  Also, what is the exact error?  Is it saying "not visible" or "not found"?  Not visible often means it's finding two elements with the selector.  Try switching from FindElement to FindElements and then have it print out the collection length.  That will tell you exactly how many matches it found.

Comment: Hi Brantley, here is the exception. No I don't have access to WebDev. This is a Oracle CC & B utility application which is built on J2EE arch.

Comment: Have put the stack trace in the main post as its too long for a comment section.

Comment: I get the same issue if I try to find the element directly by ID as well. or any other locator I know so far.

Comment: Just one more question for you.  Since it's an ID, have you tried other "By" selectors?  There is by.id("headerDivision") or by.cssSelector("#headerDivision") or to go specific by.cssSelector("body div table#headerTable") etc.  Also remind me if hitting F12 opens up IE's developer tools in IE7... it's been a while.

Comment: No Luck. Nothing opens when I press F12 in IE7. Has it got something to do with the IE settings or IE security setting or IE capabilities mentioned in the code?

Comment: So here is the problem.  I'm not sure if 1. the element isn't on the page, 2. IE7 just can't find the element, 3. or if IE is finding too many of that element.  The main part of testing is isolation and that hasn't happened yet.  You should be able to "view source" right?  Save that source into a html text file then open it up in Chrome.  Unless the raw html calls IE only software, you should be able to use the Chrome console to figure out which of those three problems you have.

Comment: Hi, I have done that.The code I have shared here is from the "view source" of web page. I don't have access to dev code. The element is there on the page, else it wouldnt have shown in the view source. The element I am looking for is a single element.Even I have a feeling that IE cant find the element, but why. Thats why I had raised this request here :)..