# Selenium (java) can't get text from nested element without printing it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I try to get text from title of modal pop-up window. On the page there are many such windows - each with uniqe id. In each such modal window all elements have the same class names so first I need to point to the correct window and then look for particular element.
So I do it with this code:

```
public String getRFRTitle(String rfrNumber) {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("rfr-details-dialog-"+rfrNumber)).
            findElement(By.className("modal-title")).getText();  
}
```

But it's not displaying for me anything.
What I have found is that when I print this title text before, this function works correctly.
I added this before returning value from the function:

```
System.out.println("tite: "+ driver.findElement(By.id("rfr-details-dialog-"+rfrNumber)).
        findElement(By.className("modal-title")).getText());
```

I tried with initialisation of variables before returning text but without luck.
I can go with my workaround but I'm curious is this Java or Selenium issue.

Comment: I've never seen anything like this before, and I use getText().equals("text") (no System.out.println) all the time.  My guess is that it is a waiting issue.  See if you can wait for an element to be present, and then get the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will most likely be a timeout issue. The following might work for you and if it doesn't, the stacktrace will give you more feedback.

```
By locator = By.cssSelector("#rfr-details-dialog-" + rfrNumber + " .modal-title");
int timeoutInSeconds = 10;

WebElement foundElement = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, timeoutInSeconds).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));

System.out.println("tite: " + foundElement.getText());
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I didn't knew that I can use such locator for modal popups: By.cssSelector("#rfr-details-dialog-" + rfrNumber + " .modal-title");